# verwenden für/zu etwas

Tags: preposition, verb

I am curious about *verwenden für/zu etwas*:

> - Er verwendet den Computer *zum* Briefschreiben.
> - Ich verwendete mein Erspartes *für* den Kauf neuer Möbel.

Can I use *zu* in the second sentence, too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, no problem. Both ways.

> Example 1: Er verwendet den Computer fürs Briefschreiben.

> Example 2: Ich verwendete meine Ersparnis (*or:* mein Erspartes) zum Kauf neuer Möbel.